# How to replace multiple text into div tags using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, editing, text-editing

I'm a new user of Notepad ++ and I need your help.
I have several pages templates using shortcodes like this:

```
[div] Block Text1 [/div]
[div] Block Text2 [/div]
```

I'd like to find a fast way to paste various text for each template.

```
Text 1 will go to Block Text1
Text 2 will go to Block Text2, etc
```

Any fast tricks you recommend to:
1/ Select only Block Text1 without the '[div]'
2/ Replace with the second text?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you clarify what the file looks like before, and how you want it to look after? I think what you're trying to do is possible but it's not quite clear exactly what your goal is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not clear it's the first time I'm using the editor here! So now I hope it's better? I have edited the question.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but Notepad++ can do search-and-replace with regular expressions, so that's probably the route you want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a former Notepad++ Contributing Developer. Notepad++ does not have this feature as of yet. It's supposedly "in the works"™ You can use Find and Replace like this:

```
Find: [div1]*[/div1]
Replace: [div1]code whatever[/div1]
```

That is really the only option I can think of.

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you think I can use macro and replace each time with a different text?

Comment: @user260187 check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362444/how-to-write-macro-for-notepad (PS: if my answer is the solution to your question, mark it as the answer :) )